# Общий доступ к съемному диску - Windows 7

Tags: windows, доступ, диск

Здравствуйте.
Нужна помощь в вопросе общего доступа к съемному диску.

Установлена ОС Windows 7 Professional SP1, подключен съёмный жесткий диск(видится как флешка).
Пытаюсь дать права доступа к этому диску: правой кнопкой-Свойства-Доступ.
Далее Кнопка "Общий доступ" она не активна.

Заходил в расширенную настройку давал всем права, отключал через Центр управления сетями парольный доступ, а также
дал там всем доступ.

НО Кнопка "Общий доступ" **не активна** для диска.
Перелопатил интернет, но так и не нашел решение.

**Как сделать Общий доступ к диску?**

Просьба помочь в данном вопросе.

P.S На том же диске создаю папку с файлами, кнопка "Общий доступ" активна!!!!!!
Делаю доступ, все работает!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать через консоль

Пуск-Выполнить

```
cmd
```

Затем в командной строке

```
net share d=d:  

net share <имя ресурса>=<диск:>
```

`net share` - команда управления папками общего доступа